# Bootstrap: How to override dynamic position of popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would adjust the placement in the bootstrap core but I'd like to keep my bootstrap-sass gem update-able. There isn't a variable for popover offset and I only need to offset 1 type of popover.

[image]

The top depicts the issue. The bottom is my adjustment using chrome dev tools. If I commit this change to my css, Bootstrap's dynamic placement readjusts and it looks like the above case again. Is there a way to have the popover automatically appear within the limits of it's parent div? If not, how do I overcome the dynamic popover placement with negative margins?

UPDATE:
Adding the code. This the resulting HTML for the button group. The popover on the first link works, you can ignore it.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-section pull-right">
  <a href="/sections/edit_section_text/118" class="noprint btn active-workers hidden-phone bs-popover btn-primary" data-content="<ul id="sectionworkers" class="unstyled"><li><img alt="Avatar" class="avatar" height="25" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar.php?d=mm&gravatar_id=9ac2c7fd1c8e43cd5b4d73d3cb585973" width="25" /> <small>Ben</small></li></ul> <!-- #sectionworkers -->" data-placement="bottom" data-target="#s118section" id="edit_btn118" rel="popover" data-original-title="Active Users: ">
    <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Edit
  </a><option>View revision...</option>

  <a href="#" class="noprint btn bs-popover" data-content="<select></select>" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" id="hist_btn" rel="popover" data-original-title="View and difference revisions"><i class="icon-time"></i> History</a>

  <div class="popover popover-offset fade bottom in" style="top: 30px; left: 155.5px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="popover-inner">
      <h3 class="popover-title">
        View and difference revisions
      </h3>
      <div class="popover-content">
        <select></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've examined pretty much every other related question. There seems to have been an "offset" parameter that has since been deprecated. "placement" can receive a function but that function just returns 1 of 4 strings - top | bottom  | left | right. I will need to select the popover div after initializing, whith jquery, and add the negative margin offset -_-

Comment: Do you have example code? It looks like you have your popover attached to your button group rather than your History button.

Comment: It's on the history button. Code is now in the question. Turns out I can't select then apply a fix class - the popover is placed when the btn is clicked then removed from the DOM. The convenience of dynamically placed popovers is being very inconvenient.

Comment: Adding `$('.bs-popover').live('click', function(e) {$(this).next().addClass('popover-offset');});` only works on the first click. Using `toggleClass` works on every other click. The easiest way to do this might just be changing bootstrap-popover.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading Archonic's PR and FATs response, I investigated the template he spoke of.

If you copy Bootstrap's template and specify it in your popover options you can inject classes at that point, which at least solved the problem for me.

```
$el.popover(
  placement: 'top',
  trigger: 'manual', 
  html: true, 
  content: @popoverContent, 
  container: '#mycontainer',
  template: '<div class="popover my_ace_class_name"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
)
```

Comment: Did you post a rape joke on stackoverflow?

Comment: Totally did not consider this. Edited - Sorry dude.

Comment: @lucygenik The squiggly brackets are missing. Might not be obvious for some beginners. $el.popover({...});

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with 2 lines in bootstrap-tooltip.js and will make a pull request. This accommodates the addition of any style you want which can fix any placement issues you may have with tooltips or popovers.

In bootstrap-tooltip.js, just before `this.$element.trigger('shown')` in `show: function ()`, add:

```
$tip.addClass(this.options.class)
```

Then just before `this.$element.trigger('hidden')` in `hide: function ()`, add

```
$tip.removeClass(this.options.class)
```

Then when initializing the tooltip or popover, add your style like so:

```
$('.bs-popover').popover({html:true, trigger:'click', class:'whatever-you-want'})
```

Then of course declare `.whatever-you-want` in your css.

It should have been so much easier than this -_-. You're welcome!

Comment: This pull request, if accepted will solve this issue for 3.0 https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/7173

Comment: Update: I screwed up the tests with the above pull request - here's the new one that's been open for months https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/7186